# Generic Inquiry in Acumatica Mobile App

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We created a bunch of Generic Inquiries in our Acumatica instance and now want to make some of them also accessible via Acumatica mobile application. What is the recommended approach to include Generic Inquiry into the Mobile SiteMap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Acumatica Generic Inquiries can be created with or without parameters:

- if a GI does not have any parameters defined, it will only contain the **Result** grid, like the **Business Accounts GI (GIMB0001)** below:
  [image]
- a GI with parameters will instead contain both the **Filter_** top-level form and the **Result** grid, like the **Business Accounts Filtered GI (GIMB0002)** below:
  [image]

The code snippet below shows how to map both a GI without parameters and a GI with parameters utilizing Acumatica's [Mobile Site Map Definition Language](https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=0d4f5b50-7959-4532-8b0e-6352d2a8ee84) (aka MSDL):

```
sitemap {
  add folder "Mobile GIs"{
    icon = "system://Pen"
    type = "ListFolder"
    add item "GIMB0001" {
      displayName = "Business Accounts GI"
      icon = "system://Culture"
    }
    add item "GIMB0002" {
      displayName = "Business Accounts Filtered GI"
      icon = "system://Culture"
    }
  }
}

add screen "GIMB0001" {
  type = SimpleScreen
  add container "Result" {
    fieldsToShow = 4
    add field "BusinessAccount"
    add field "Type"
    add field "Status"
    add field "ClassID"
    add field "Country"
    add field "City"
    add field "Email"
    add field "Phone1"
    add field "Web"
  }
}

add screen "GIMB0002" {
  type = FilterListScreen
  add container "Filter_" {
    add field "Status"
    add field "ClassID"
  }
  add container "Result" {
    fieldsToShow = 4
    add field "BusinessAccount"
    add field "Type"
    add field "Status"
    add field "ClassID"
    add field "Country"
    add field "City"
    add field "Email"
    add field "Phone1"
    add field "Web"
  }
}
```

**To apply changes defined in the code snippet above to a local Acumatica ERP instance**, you can save the entire code snippet as an ***.msd*** file and place it into the ***App_Data\Mobile folder*** of your local website. After restarting the mobile app, your changes should be applied to the mobile site map. To package ***.msd*** file into a customization, you should simply add it using the ***Files*** section of the **Customization Manager**.

The main differences between mappings for **Business Accounts GI (GIMB0001)** and **Business Accounts Filtered GI (GIMB0002)** are:

- the type of the mobile site map screen: **SimpleScreen** for a GI without parameters and **FilterListScreen** for a GI with parameters
- the number of defined containers: **1** for a GI without parameters and **2** for a GI with parameters

Comment: Is it possible to add custom parameters?  For instance, my GI has 4 custom checkbox parameters.